# Pattern Matching Using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, pattern-matching

I need to match bellow mentioned patterns using SQL.

1. "* THANK YOU"
2. "* MUSIC *"
3. "I LIKE * MUSIC"
4. "I LIKE * MUSIC AND * PAINTING"

Input strings will look like this,
"HI THANK YOU" -> should match "* THANK YOU"
"I LIKE MUSIC VERY MUCH" -> should match "* MUSIC *"

Is there a way to do this using standard SQL syntax.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the asterisks typos or part of the data?  Why does the second target string match data `2.` but not `3.` or `4.` ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "standard SQL"?  Are you really looking for a solution which works on both Oracle and MySQL RDBMS ?

Comment: Yes * are part of data. Actually they are regexps. Ideal case would be SQL query works on any dbms with small alterations.

Comment: look for text mining solutions. this is not a *classic* database problem.

Comment: As @haki says this is *not* the sort of question which is solvable by standard SQL.  Every DBMS handles pattern matching using slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle MySQL Sample Queries:

Case insensitive:

```
select * from database where column like '%THANK YOU%';
```

Case sensitive:

```
select * from database where column LIKE BINARY '%THANK YOU%';
```

Case insensitive:

```
select * from database where column REGEXP 'THANK YOU';
```

Oracle Queries:

```
select * from database WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, 'THANK YOU', 'i')
```

You can use LIKE in Oracle, but case insensitivity setup depends on the version.

Case sensitive:

```
select * from database WHERE column LIKE 'THANK YOU';
```

There is a lot of discussion about making Oracle's like case insensitive. It's easier to use the reg_exp version for that and set the `i` flag for case insensitivity.

**Update**
The original question was actually opposite of my first answer, and it has really opened up my head about quite a few apps that I'm building for datamining. Actually had this idea last night but the original poster posted it before I did (Fiddle was down). You can make Regex match both sides of the REGEXP function in MySQL. So if you store a list of expressions into the database, then you can actually compare the list of expressions against a table of entries or a single string.

I've added an SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/701a0/2

**Note** that in the original example, the "regex" values in the database started with just an asterisk. In Regex, the actual string would need to be .* for possibly any character.

I've added a few examples for matching things like websites, US Toll Free Numbers, and gmail accounts.

```
INSERT INTO `myRegex` VALUES (1,'.* THANK YOU$'),(2,'MUSIC'),(3,'I LIKE .* MUSIC'),(4,'I LIKE .* MUSIC AND .* PAINTING'),(5,'^[0-9]?[ .-]?(800|866)'),(6,'\\.com$'),(7,'\\.net$'),(8,'\\.(gmail|googlemail)\\.'),(9,'THANK YOU');
```

Output

```
select * from myRegex where 'HI THANK YOU' REGEXP reg_expr;
```

[image]

```
select * from myRegex where 'THANK YOU MUCH' REGEXP reg_expr;
```

[image]

Comment: Oracle also supports straight LIKE operator

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but what I really want is the other way around. HI THANK YOU should be the input and result should be "* THANK YOU".

Comment: So you want to find "HI THANK YOU" literally? If "HI THANK YOU" isn't in the text, then it would not match. You would have to use conditionals and build IF statements.

Comment: @APC if they were going for case insensitivity you can't get it with Oracle without using the rexexp_like operator.

Comment: In my case regexp is stored in the table. What I need is to find the correct regexp for the input text. "HI THANK YOU" is the input and the matched regexp is the "* THANK YOU". "* THANK YOU" is the value stored in the db table.

Comment: Is this for Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Generic solution would be ideal but, for the time being MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this using MySQL,

SELECT * FROM knowledge WHERE 'HI THANK YOU' REGEXP pattern_col;

pattern_col holds regexps.

Comment: Was just testing this myself. Had to turn in.